# Sub-sub query can't access table defined in outer scope

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Table `Races` has the columns `Time`, `Racetrack` and `Racer`.

Table `Racetracks` has the columns `Name` and `Length`.

The following query does a complicated selection to find a single row of the `Racetracks` table (the lower part) and then calculates certain properties of this racetrack (the upper part). One of those properties is the average racetime here.

```
SELECT
    (select avg(Time) from Races where Racetrack = t.Name) as AverageTime
    /* more lines like the one above to calculate information about this track */
FROM (select * from Racetracks
      /* complicated where clauses to select a particular racetrack */
      limit 1
     ) as t;
```

I want to modify the query a little bit. Instead of the average racetime of all races only the best time of each racer should be averaged. This is what I tried:

```
SELECT
    (select avg(BestTime) from (select min(Time) as BestTime from Races where Racetrack = t.Name group by Racer) as b) as AverageTime
    /* more lines like the one above to calculate information about this track */
FROM (select * from Racetracks
      /* complicated where clauses to select a particular racetrack */
      limit 1
     ) as t;
```

Altough the following error is thrown by MySQL:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.Name' in 'where clause'
```

This seems related https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126339/subquery-cant-find-column-from-superquerys-join but I can't figure out how to rewrite my query in a way that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this.  You *can* precalculate the values for all race tracks:

```
SELECT (select avg(BestTime)
        from (select RaceTrack, Racer, min(Time) as BestTime
              from Races 
              group by RaceTrack, Racer
             ) r
        where r.Racetrack = t.Name 
       ) as AverageTime
    /* more lines like the one above to calculate information about this track */
FROM (select * from Racetracks
      /* complicated where clauses to select a particular racetrack */
      limit 1
     ) as t;
```

For one race track, it doesn't matter if the logic is a subquery or in the `from` clause.  If you were doing multiple race tracks at once, I would recommend pre-summarizing in the `from` clause.

Comment: That works but is pretty slow with a lot of racetracks, I'll accept this until there is a better answer.

Comment: @timakro . . . If you ask another question with the complete query, it might be possible to improve performance.